# update panel CSV generation cache issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

On a page with update panel on a button click I have put some code to generate CSV .

When I click on Open in File dialog CSV file shown comes from browser cache.Every time it shows old csv.I have checked on server the csv file is created new but browser show old files.

Comment: What is CSV  Commas Separated Values ? I think that some code may help...

Answer (score 1):

Rather than impractical work arounds, you should instead focus on changing the servers cache control settings, provided you are on an apache server, then update your .htaccess file with:

```
<filesMatch "\.(csv)$">
FileETag None
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
</ifModule>
</filesMatch>
```

This will switch off caching of .csv files.

Answer (score 0):

A Simple way to avoid that is to add a random string on the end of the file, something like

**/YourFile.csv?rnd=4707**

or you can place some cache headers to not let it cache, for example

```
    Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(-4));
    Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
    Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
```